# Laravel and ZipArchive - nvalid or uninitialized Zip object

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I need to create a zip using some file on my server.
I used [Zipper](https://github.com/Chumper/Zipper) from here but it does not allow me to add a custom name while adding a file so I switched on [ZipArchive](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php).

Here the code:

```
$zipper      = new \ZipArchive();

foreach ($tracks as $track) {
   $trackName = $track->name;
   $trackPath = $customUploads->getCustomTrackFilePath($track, true);
   $zipper->addFile($trackPath, $trackName);
}

$zipper->close();
```

Here the error:

> ErrorException in PlaylistController.php line 223:
>   ZipArchive::addFile(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object

I tried to add this control and when execute it I get the `dd()` message so looks like it is not able to create.

```
if( $zipper->open($zipName) !== true ){
            dd('no');
        }
```

The strange thing is that with the library linked at the top the zip is created.
Where is my error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing 2nd parameter `flags` of `Zip::open` function. Please check manual here http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.open.php

```
$zipper = $zip->open('test.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
```

Comment: Damn, you're right, thanks. I have added the solution to your answer.